# Presto: join two large tables directly or filter them first?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, presto

I need to join 2 or more large tables(> 100,000,000 rows) in Presto SQL. My environment limits resources by query time and resource allocation.

It is my understanding that Presto loads the JOINED table into memory while scanning and filtering the FROM table.

Currently I am dealing with a query failing because of insufficient resources. In the query more than 2 tables with 1to1 relations are being joined.

While the FROM table is being filtered with WHERE clauses as well as INNER JOINS to smaller tables, the JOINED tables would be loaded into memory.

Would it be more efficient to filter all the large tables by the smaller table in a CTE first, then joining the CTE?

Original query:

```sql
SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM large_table1 l1
JOIN small_table s1 ON s1.f1 = l1.f1
LEFT JOIN large_table2 l2 ON l2.f2 = l1.f2
```

After extraction:

```sql
WITH temp AS(
  SELECT f2, f3
  FROM large_table2 l2
  JOIN small_table s1 ON s1.f2 = l2.f2
)

SELECT f1, f2, f3
FROM large_table1 l1
JOIN small_table s1 ON s1.f1 = l1.f1
LEFT JOIN temp t2 ON t2.f2 = l1.f2
```

Will the second one always be more efficient?

Comment: Note that your second query doesn't even use the CTE, possibly a typo.  But to answer your question, Postgres will materialize the CTE, which step will slow down your intended second version.  So just use the first version.

Comment: Ah yeah, fixed that now.
My issue is more with the memory rather than the time at the moment. Could this still be beneficial in a memory limit case?

Comment: If the CTE gets materialized (the case if you're really using Postgres as you have tagged your question), then the memory footprint would get _larger_.  The memory required for the execution of the query should otherwise be the same.